# Linux dropfolder where users can't delete files

Tags: permissions, filesystem, samba, directory, chmod

I am working on a file server project for school and I am using samba to share the folders. I have been playing around with the folder permissions but I can't seem to figure out how to make a drop only like folder. This is what I want to achieve:

- Owner (server account): Full control `(chmod number 7xx)`
- Group (users that sign in to the samba server) : Only place (drop) files,so this means don't open/edit/delete files in the folder `(chmod number x?x)`
- others : no access `(chmod number xx0)`

I have tried a lot of different chmod settings but never achieved the wanted result. Is this even possible? I googled a lot but couldn't really find a concluding answer.

Maybe a way to set permissions on files whenever they are placed in the folder?

If you need more information about the samba configuration or anything else please ask!

Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Remember, there are permissions for both files and folders.  You can make a folder read or write only.  Also, a folder is normally executable, but if you don't make it executable, it can't be listed or entered, but files can be read or written to if specified (and if appropriate permissions are set).

Comment: @MartyFried I figured that out, also it's okay for people to list the items in the folder but not open them. So what permissions do I need to set on the files and folder? Thank you for the reply!

Comment: You should edit your question, then.  But my guess is you want the files to be `rw--w----`(620).  If they are executable files, then it would be `rwx--wx----` (730).

Comment: @MartyFried You've [explained](http://askubuntu.com/q/529774#comment722924_529774) it mostly backwards. Actually, executable permission on a folder gives the right to access its contents by name (as well as to `cd` to the folder, as you say). Read permission on a folder enables you to list names of its entries (though not to view even their metadata). See [this example](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8521597/) and [Gilles's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13891) to [Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13858/11938)

Comment: @EliahKagan: Thanks for pointing that out; too bad I can't edit a comment.  TBH, I have little experience with multi-user systems, but I wanted mainly to point in the general direction, which is why I didn't try to enter an actual answer. I was probably in too much of a hurry at the time, and didn't think it through clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this procedure.

Create shared folder and give right permission:

```
  mkdir /pathYouWant/share
  chmod 770 /pathYouWant/share
```

This gives no access to other.

```
  chmod +t /pathYouWant/share
```

This mode, according to [**chmod manual page**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chmod.1.html):

```
   The  restricted  deletion  flag  or  sticky  bit is a single bit, whose
   interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it  prevents
   unprivileged  users  from  removing or renaming a file in the directory
   unless they  own  the  file  or  the  directory
```

As told by Marty Fried files created in the share folder should have the right permissions and this can be achieved with [**samba share masks**](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html) in `smb.conf`:

```
  create mask = 440
  directory mask = 550
```

Windows programs shouldn't try to remove read-only files unless `delete readonly` option is set to yes.

```
  delete readonly = no
```

Also if you want to hide all file in share folder:

```
  veto files = /*/
  delete veto files = no
```

According to samba manual these directive:

> What happens if the user tries to delete a directory that contains
>   vetoed files? This is where the delete veto files option comes in. If
>   this Boolean option is set to yes, the user can delete both the
>   regular files and the vetoed files in the directory, and the directory
>   itself is removed. If the option is set to no, the user cannot delete
>   the vetoed files, and consequently the directory is not deleted
>   either. From the user's perspective, the directory appears empty, but
>   cannot be removed.

After this configuration, the only problem left is that user can still delete his/her own files even if he/she do not see it (It is unclear to us why).

So we decide to follow the_Seppi suggestion to complete the task and Bram Driesen did a script that changes file ownership to the host pc.

He used `incron` to fire the script whenever a file is placed in the folder, following [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692557/2932698) as guide to set it up.

Comment: I tried this method today but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you explain what goes wrong?

Comment: I think I found the problem now. Let me test it real quick

Comment: okay so this is the problem. The user that signs in can place files in the folder. That's okay. BUT he can still delete his own files that he placed in the folder and also view what is in all the files that are in the folder. He can't delete files from the host though.

Comment: do you know a solution to my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that you want user not able to remove his own files. Now I see that I did a mistake. Tomorrow I'll try another way, and I'll give you a feedback if I found it.

Comment: I'm very thankful! I'm looking forward to your response! Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17584/discussion-between-letizia-and-bram-driesen).

Comment: Did you try my changes? I'm curious to know if we found solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your problem is not solvable so easily. If a user has write permission in a directory, he can also delete files. Even if he wasn't able to delete them, he could still fill a file with zeros, which would be a deletion of data, but not of the filesystem node.

---

An idea which I once used:

You create a cronjob, which recusively removes the write permission of every file in a directory tree (like every file in `/home/guest`).

Note that you can't simply use `chmod g-w -R /home/guest`. This would take the write bit off the directories too, making it impossible to place new files there. So you'd need to iterate over every file and remove it's group write bit.

The interval of the cronjob execution is up to you - back then I set it to 10 minutes. I don't know your environment, so I can't give you a recommendation.

Unfortunately I don't have this script any more, so you'll have to do some bash scripting to get it to work. But seriously, I doubt that this is an efficient method.

Comment: Hmm looks like a solution but not the ideal solution. But hey, thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

We can modify the files and folders but can't delete.

To remove the attributes, run the following commands:

For files:

```
sudo chattr -R -a file.txt
```

For directories:

```
sudo chattr -R -a dir1/
```