# Folder permissions: only allow user to write (not read or delete)

Tags: permissions, samba

I'm having this upload folder where a user is only allowed to write files. After he wrote the file he is not allowed to read or delete it.

How can this be done?

Comment: Try [Linux dropfolder where users can't delete files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/529774/linux-dropfolder-where-users-cant-delete-files)

Comment: Thank you, but i'm looking for an easier solution...

Comment: @ThomasMore it depends on what you consider easy.. as the link provided by Letizia looks pretty straight forward...

Comment: Running a script etc is a bit of a challenge

Comment: Only one user, or all users, or other users?

Comment: As you can see in [Linux dropfolder where users can't delete files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/529774/linux-dropfolder-where-users-cant-delete-files) we did not find how to prevent user to delete it owns files in writable folder. I think probably, studying carefully samba manual, there is a way, but certainly change the owner or move files to a different folder it works for sure

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to allow a user to write only. The user should have read pemission to be able to write in a file.

What I can suggest is having multiple directories, for example:

- here your upload folder : upload
- here another folder : master-upload

the user files would be files in the upload folder and a cron that runs every 5 mins moves the files to the master-upload where he has no permission.